# Using Earphones/Headphones with mic to give voice commands in DIY alexa on raspberryPi zero/3b/3b+

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-zero, microphone

Can I use Using Earphones/Headphones with a mic to give voice commands in DIY Alexa on raspberryPi zero/3b/3b+ by connecting the 3.5mm male jack to the board via a USB type c/ micro USB adapter as the 3.5mm jack is only for audio OUT?

Can I use Bluetooth speakers to receive the audio while giving input via a USB mic/mic array

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** you can connect an analog 3.5mm mic via a USB sound card to your Raspberry Pi.

**And Yes** you can use a Bluetooth speaker to play sound from a Raspberry Pi.

Ref.:

GUI method: https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/bluetooth-audio-raspberry-pi-3/

CLI method: https://pacmans-revenge.blogspot.com/2018/08/raspberry-pi-bluetooth-speakers.html